# Change package.json in vue project to do custom build mode

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, package.json

Is this the correct way to change my vue 2  package.json serve script to compile under a new custom build mode "devserver"?

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service lint --fix && vue-cli-service serve --open --mode devserver",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint --fix"
  },
```

Assuming I have a .env.devserver file in my root folder?

Comment: I was just trying to verify I was doing it the correct way, and not a horrible hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are doing the right thing, but it is not clear what the problem is.
Try this [naming](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)

- env.devserver.local // Compiles and hot-reloads for development

```json
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service lint --fix && vue-cli-service serve --open --mode devserver.local",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint --fix"
},
```

Comment: Thanks! didn't know that non local didn't hot reload.